# How to fill a color inside circle in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I have to fill a circle with yellow color but if I use fill tool it just fills the borders. I want to fill the inside.

Here is a picture for example:

[image]

I just want to fill the inside with yellow by one click, rather than using a brush tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of stroke **and** fill.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change the selected Material. By default it will be "**Solid Stroke**", if you select "**Solid Fill**" before you use the **Fill Bucket** tool - it should fill the body of the circle.

Long story short - You need a material will a Fill color enabled. You can also change the settings of the current material.

[image: Material selection]